# can not run java inside grsec chroot

Tags: security, java, chroot, grsec

java runs well inside common chroot.

however in a grsec hardened chroot it complains it has no enough memory to build VM.

any ideas of how to make it run cause i really need a hardened chroot.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally Java plays well with grsec.

However there are an option in grsec that break things bad for Java.

Seems you have that option enabled in your kernel.

Check it at:

```
[*] Grsecurity 
  Customize Configuration  --->
    PaX  --->
      Miscellaneous hardening features  ---> 
        [ ] Sanitize all freed memory
```

Make sure `Sanitize all freed memory` option is disabled, recompile kernel(IMO it can not be managed via sysctl) and retry.

Comment: seems to make sense, trying

Comment: yes, it works, however i'm not totally satisfied with this option disabled... perhaps any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details: exact text of error message, which JVM you're using, etc.

I had similar issue running java on 32-bit Gentoo Hardened (also grsec, but without chroot): https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344135

You can try to work around this issue by changing your jvm.cfg to use "client" instead of "server", for ex.:

```
[jvm.cfg.patch]
--client IF_SERVER_CLASS -server
--server KNOWN
+-client KNOWN
```

Also you can try to run java with -client and/or -Xmx256m options.